# Azure - Is there a way to generalize the Image after capturing it already?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Recently, I tried to generalize a specific VM in Azure to be used as an image for a future scale set.

After doing that (the wrong way), I tried to create a VM using this image and I got this error -

```
"OS Provisioning for VM 'MyVM_10' did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM
guest agent was detected running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image
(with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it
properly for use as an image"
```

Which means that I did not sysprep it properly.
Is there a way to sysprep it now? Or do I have to start all over again and there is no use of the image file that was created in this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stop your original VM and use this image to create a VM. Then I think you will not meet this error log. Then you could login this VM and sysprep it and use this VM to create a new image.

If it does not work, I suggest you could download this image's VHD to local. Using this VHD to create a VM on Hyper-V and sysprep it. Then upload this VHD to Azure and use this VHD to create a image. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/capture-image-resource#create-image-from-a-vhd-in-a-storage-account).

Comment: The problem is that The VM is already deleted.. But I will try to do the second part.. It's weird that there's no such option in Azure and I have to download it manually.. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Drxxd When you try to use this image create a VM, you get the error log? You delete original VM, you could use this image to create a VM, but only one VM.

Comment: @Drxxd If you still meet this error, you need download it to you local and sysprep in your local Hyper-V.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks. Yeah it happens only when making a scale set, Now trying to make a single VM

Comment: Hi, do you delete your original VM's VHD. If no, you had better use this VHD to create a new VM.

Comment: It gives me the error even when creating a single VM using this image.. I will try to download it and create a VM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162962/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-drxxd).